# How many number of threads are OK to use in my c++ application

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, cpu-cores

So my professor once told me in college don't use more threads in your program then your PC physically has.

I'm confused, if you look at my system resource allocation, I'm currently using 4811 threads i.e.,
[image: My Computers Resource information]

and I only have 16 thread processor.

So my questions is, can my c++ program significantly exceed the number of threads my computer physically has?

Also, what happens when you exceed the number of threads your computer has, the OS queues them correct ?

Comment: This is all the execution threads, not just whatever C++ application you're running, at this time. And just because an execution thread exists, it doesn't mean that it's actually running and requires the attention of an actual CPU thread. You can have a million threads created (presuming sufficient memory), and if all of them are waiting for an I/O event, none of your actual 16 CPU threads will have anything to do.

Comment: You can allocate threads until your system runs out of resources. BUT! The more active threads you have in excess of the available cores, the more time you will waste switching back and forth between the threads. If you have a lot of threads that are active all of the time it's in your best interests to aggregate some of those threads or throttle the workload so that there are fewer threads. See [threadpools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) for one way to do this.

Comment: Unrelated: Take a look at [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) for a more detailed look at what's going on than Task manager presents.

Comment: Your professor is both right and wrong. Or is speaking in general terms. It's not uncommon for large scale programs to have dozens or even hundreds of threads. It's just most of these threads are blocked waiting for I/O or some event to happen. A blocked thread uses no CPU resources, but typically incurs memory usage since a stack frame has to be allocated for it.